# How to specify a list to start with decimal number?

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a page and name is all_list.php which include other three pages, list_one.php, list_two.php, and list_three_php. On this three pages I have a list where by I want to display the list in order. The style on the three pages is the same.
I want my list to be in decimal format, which it does. But when the list on list_two.php and three are displayed they start from 1. I want the list on list_two to to start from 2 and the one on list_three.php to start from 3.

For example i should have something like this

Summary of Programming Languages(My Heading)

1. Layout Languages
   1.1. HTML 5
2. Breakdown of the 2 from the 9 Most In-Demand Programming Languages
   2.1. SQL.
   2.2. Java
3. Programming Languages
   3.1. Java
   3.2. PHP
   3.3. Python

Here is my code

My Style:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .my_list
    {
        font : 12px Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;      
    }
    p
    {
        margin: 0.33em;
    }
    h4, h5
    {
        display: block;
        margin: 0.33em;
        font-weight: bold;     
    }
    h4
    {
         font-size : 14px;
    }
    h5
    {
         font-size : 13px;
    }
    /* ul
    {
        margin-left: -3.3em
    } */
    ol 
    {
        counter-reset: item;
    }
    ol li 
    {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    ol li:before
    {
        content: counters(item, ".")".";
        counter-increment: item;
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 100%;
        right: 10px;
    } 
</style>
```

all_list.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>All my List</title>
</head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">         
                <div class ="content">              
                    <h1>Summary of Programming Languages</h1>
                    <?php include "list_one.php";?>         
                    <?php include "list_two.php";?>             
                    <?php include "list_three.php";?>                                                
                </div>
            </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

This the Output I get results:

[image: Results]

I want this:

[image: what i need]

I have tried to make ol on list_two to start with 2 and ol in list_three.php to start with 3, which works but this does not support decimal. I want to display the list in decimal format.

I don't want to use hard coded numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Don't post samples on sites that require signing in in order to view them.

Comment: @ The Sexiest Man in Jamaica and @Mihriban Minaz, I have fixed the url.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for welcoming me. I'm new on SO. Your help will be highly expected. I will try my best to make my questions clear.

Comment: You have better show us the other 3 script s that get included

Comment: Basicall you have to have all the sublists crfeated inside the first `<ol>` I would expect your 3 includes all have selerate `<ol>` tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Custom List Start Number

In HTML5 you can specify a [`start` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-start) on `ol` elements.

> The `start` attribute, if present, must be a valid integer giving the ordinal value of the first list item.

Here's a two-item list starting at 98:

```html
<ol start=98>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ol>
```

### Decimal Places

For supporting decimal places you can use CSS to add in generated content (via the `::before) pseudo-element) and counters (using the`counter-increment` property).

What the below code example does is:

1. Implement a `myListNumber` counter which gets incremented (by 1) every time an `ol` element which is a direct child of the `body` element is found.*
2. Add this counter value to a `::before` `pseudo-element` on each inner-list `li` (using `content: counter(myListNumber) '.'` - the `'.` is the decimal place).
3. Absolutely position this `3px` away from the automatic list number (using `left: -28px` (as our list already has `25px` left padding)).

* *In your case you'd want to use `.content > ol` instead of `body > ol` as your `ol` elements are contained within a `.content` element.*

```css
body > ol {
  counter-increment: myListNumber;
}

ol ol {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

ol ol li {
  position: relative;
}

ol ol li::before {
  content: counter(myListNumber) '.';
  position: absolute;
  left: -28px;
}
```

```html
<ol start=1>
  <li>
    Foo
    <ol>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Baz</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol start=2>
  <li>
    Foo
    <ol>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Baz</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<ol start=3>
  <li>
    Foo
    <ol>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Baz</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks James Donnelly. It seems not to work for me cause of the div's i have.-